# Cmake can't find UHD when building init_usrp example

Tags: uhd

When attempting to build the UHD init_usrp example in ../host/examples/init_usrp, cmake fails to find UHD.  The CMakeLists.txt file for that example contains a line find_package(UHD 4.1.0 REQUIRED).  Whatever is not happening there casues UHD_LIBRARIES and UHD_INCLUDE_DIRS not to be set in UHDConfig.cmake which then fails when it tries to perform get_filename_component.

I've built and installed UHD-4.4.0.0 from the master branch and am using cmake 3.26.

I'm at a loss for why it can't find UHD and set those vars correctly.  I've tried taking the file FindUHD.cmake from gnuradio but that has not helped.

Comment: Not sure if it has something to do with cmake stripping the runtime path or not.  But I figured that would be picked up by LD_LIBRARY_PATH containing /opt/uhd/lib64.

Comment: In UHDConfig.cmake, UHD_DIR isn't being set properly.  It should be /opt/uhd which is a  symbolic link to my actual UHD dir in /opt.  However it is /opt/uhd/lib64/cmake/uhd.  I'm not sure why this is.  If I change UHD_LIB_HINTS and UHD_INCLUDE_HINTS to include the proper directories under /opt/uhd then everything works fine.  But it seems kind of hackish.